# Render Elements other than Routes inside RouterProvider - react-router v6

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have route configuration with `routes` from `useRoutes()` hook which already works properly

```
<HashRouter>
  {routes}
  <NavigationBar />
</HashRouter>
```

Now I have to migrate it to new `createHashRouter()`. The problem is that, docs states that it has to be rendered like

```
<RouterProvider router={/* return value from createHashRouter */} />
```

leaving no way to render the `<NavigationBar />`. Also the `RouteProvider` doesn't accept any children if I try to render like

```
<RouterProvider router={/* return value from createHashRouter */} >
  <NavigationBar />
</RouterProvider>
```

It throws `Property 'children' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & RouterProviderProps'`

Another method

```
<main>
  <RouterProvider ... />
  <NavigationBar />
</main>
```

Here `NavigationBar` doesn't have access to navigation properties like router hooks.

There is no mention in the docs to how to implement the above scenario

Comment: Where do you get this info? Here is shows something very different: https://reactrouter.com/en/main/router-components/hash-router

Comment: Here it is for [new method](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/create-hash-router) of creating route r and this is for [migration](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/upgrading/v6-data#but-ive-got-stuff-between-browserrouter-and-routes)

Comment: Then you can follow the method on the link you just mentioned ;).

Comment: Yes, but my query is how can I achieve the same using `createHashRouter`. It isn't mentioned in the docs

Comment: It's here: https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/create-hash-router